# how to count number of files which already exists in a folder

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count

In a filemanagement, for moving files to another folder, i am trying to count the number of files which already exists in a folder.

```
foreach($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {
    $src_file = $checkboxfile;
    $fileName = basename($src_file);
    $new_dest = $_POST['cbdestination'];

    /* New path for this file */
    $dest_file = $MainFolderName.'/'. $new_dest . '/' . $fileName;

    echo count(file_exists($dest_file)); //this should give me the number of files which already exists
```

As 2 files are already exists, the echo produces

```
11
11
```

as output.
How can i achieve the number `2` as output?

Comment: `file_exists` returns true or false. What's the point of counting result of it?

Comment: Also, you are likely not getting the number 11, but rather the number 1 echoed twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `count` wrong. `file_exists` returns `true` or `false`. `count` is used for counting `arrays`.
Ir order to achieve what you want you can do:

```
$count = 0;  
foreach($checkboxfiles as $checkboxfile) {
    $src_file = $checkboxfile;
    $fileName = basename($src_file);
    $new_dest = $_POST['cbdestination'];

    /* New path for this file */
    $dest_file = $MainFolderName.'/'. $new_dest . '/' . $fileName;
    if(file_exists($dest_file)){
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of files in a folder by FilesystemIterator(requires `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7`)

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator('directory/location', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("Number of files: %d ", iterator_count($fi));
```

Comment: Neat method, but not what OP wanted. OP has a list of files and wants to check how many of them (if any) already exist in a given directory.